# Latex - Beamer - Table of Content - Problem: Subsections are shown above their section

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning

I want to have a nice TOC in my latex-presentation, but it get's messed up, as soon as I outsource the content to a seperate file.

Here the reduced example:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}  %% Themenwahl

\begin{document}
\frame{\tiny\tableofcontents[subsectionstyle=show/show]}
\section{Sec1}
%\subsection{Sub1}
%\begin{frame}
%    \frametitle{TEST1}
%        TEST1
%\end{frame}
\include{otherfile}
\end{document}
```

the importet otherfile is

```
\subsection{Sub2}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{TEST2}
        TEST2
\end{frame}
```

What I expect is to get a table of content with

> Sec1
>
> - Sub2

What I get

> - Sub2
>
> Sec1

[image: wrong order of TOC items]

if I uncomment the line "\subsection{Sub1}" then the Sub1 is shown in the correct place, but sub2 still at the wrong one.
[image: Sub1 correct, sub2 still strange]

If I uncomment also the complete Frame "Test1", then everything is OK
[image: everything fine]

Any Idea how I can resolve this. I want no further content in the main file. The only workaround I found was to move the section in the outsourced file ... which is OK, but not perfect, since sometimes there are two files for one section and sometimes I want to remove one of them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\input`:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}  %% Themenwahl

\begin{document}
\frame{\tiny\tableofcontents[subsectionstyle=show/show]}
\section{Sec1}
%\subsection{Sub1}
%\begin{frame}
%    \frametitle{TEST1}
%        TEST1
%\end{frame}
\input{sub}
\end{document}
```

[image]